# Problemas de conversão de String lendo dados em CSV

Tags: java, string, csv, int

Saudações Pessoal.
Estou criando um programa que lê dados de um arquivo csv. Estou tendo problemas ao ler uma String e converter para int, porque na leitura da String não é removida as aspas ("").

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""5865""
```

valor esperado 5865

Abaixo o meu código:

```
public void carregarOriginado(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {

    UploadedFile uploadedFile = event.getFile();      


    if (uploadedFile != null) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(uploadedFile.getInputstream(), "UTF-8");

        scanner.nextLine();
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String linha = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] values = linha.split(";");

            originado.setDiaEvento(getData());
            originado.setCalledcountry(values[1]);
            originado.setCalledoperator(values[2]);

            if (values[3].contains("BICS")){
                originado.setCollednode("BICS");
            }
            if (values[3].contains("MEO")){
                originado.setCollednode("PT");
            }
            originado.setLastcause(values[4]);
            originado.setCount(Integer.parseInt(values[5]));           

            originadoFacade.create(originado);
        }

    }

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();        
    context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Sucesso", "Ficheiro Carregado Com Sucesso"));        
    criarPerformance();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Faça um `replaceAll` para remover as aspas:

```java
originado.setCount(Integer.parseInt(values[5].replaceAll("\"", ""));
```